# i keep getting the error saying that my class name is not defined in python

Tags: python, class, object

I have been stuck on my program for school for over a hour with this error and i cant seem to figure out how to fix it.

import sys

class myDate:

```
#Constructer
def __init__(self, month, day, year):
    self.day = day    #Privet day
    self.month = month  #Privet month
    self.year = year   #privet year


#format for MDYYYY
def MDYYYY(self):
    print("%i/%i/%i" %(myDate.month, myDate.day, myDate.year))
    
#format for MDYY
    
#format for YYYYMD

#mutator  to set Day of the month
def setDay(self, a):
    try:
        day = int(a)
        if day < 1 or day > 31:
            raise Exception("invalid day")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Invalid day")
        sys.exit( err )
    else:
        self.__day = day
    
#Mutator to set Month of the year
def setMonth(self, a):
    try:
        month = int(a)
        if month < 1 or month > 12:
            raise Exception("invalid month")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Invalid month")
        sys.exit( err )
    else:
        self.__month = month
        
#Mutator to set the year of the date
def setYear(self, a):
    try:
        day = int(a)
        if day < 1700:
            raise Exception("invalid year")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Invalid year")
        sys.exit( err )
    else:
        self.__year = year

# accessor to get day
def getDay(self):
    return self.__day

# accessor to get the month
def getMonth(self):
    return self.__month

# accessor to get the year
def getYear(self):
    return self.__year

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print()
    print( "Instantiating object today and sorting value using .setMonth(6) .setDay(17) .setYear(2019)" )
    setDay.day = 17
    setMonth.month = 6
    setYear.year = 2019
    
    print(myDate.MDYYYY())
```

ime getting this result when i run it:
Instantiating object today and sorting value using .setMonth(6) .setDay(17) .setYear(2019)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\RCCC\Fall 2020\Python GUI\Project 1\dateformat_duxbury.py", line 8, in 
class myDate():
File "D:\RCCC\Fall 2020\Python GUI\Project 1\dateformat_duxbury.py", line 80, in myDate
print(myDate.MDYYYY())
NameError: name 'myDate' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of the formatting of your post, it seems that your method definitions are on the same indentation-level as your declaration of class myDate. This means that instead of being methods of that class, they are instead methods of the global space. You should indent all of those so that they are one level deeper than the declaration of class myDate. This explains the "name 'myDate' is not defined" error.

There are a few more errors:

1. You are using setDay, setMonth and setYear as if they were objects, which is incorrect. They should be called from an instance of class myDate. To do that, you must first create that instance and then call those methods from it like so:

Example:

```
date = myDate()
date.setDay(17)
date.setMonth(6)
date.setYear(2019)
```

2. You are using myDate.MDYYYY() which will probably not do what you intend to as myDate is a class, not an instance of a class. See the example above on how to create an instance of that class.

Don't take it the wrong way, but it sounds like you should review a tutorial on how classes work in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Your problem appears to be more of a conceptual one rather than one of implementation. I would highly recommend to go over Object-Oriented principles since you seem to be mixing up classes and objects.

For example, your specific error is in reference to this part of the code:

```py
#format for MDYYYY
def MDYYYY(self):
    print("%i/%i/%i" %(myDate.month, myDate.day, myDate.year))
```

However, have you considered whether you have any instance of myDate in that function? What you're trying to access is, in fact, the month, day and year of the specific object you will be calling MDYYYY() from. In which case, you'd need to access the object's own month, day and year variables. To that end, you access an object's internal variables using the `self` keyword.

```py
#format for MDYYYY
def MDYYYY(self):
   print("%i/%i/%i" %(self.month, self.day, self.year))
```

Now, the second issue is that of instantiating an object in your main code block.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print()
    print( "Instantiating object today and sorting value using .setMonth(6) .setDay(17) .setYear(2019)" )
    # Instantiate a myDate object here:
    myDateObject = myDate(4, 25, 2005) # You need to pass in the month, day and year values as part of your class init function

    # You call instance functions on the object itself, such as
    myDateObject.setDay(7)
    myDateObject.setMonth(6)
    myDateObject.setYear(2019) 
    
    # Call the MDYYYY function on the myDateObject instance and not the myDate class
    print(myDateObject.MDYYYY())
```

Again, I would highly recommend to go over some OOP basics. Hope this helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear as to why in your `main` section you're accessing class methods without instantiating a class first. Your comment says that you're instantiating the class, but you really aren't. It should be something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    md = myDate(1, 1, 1900)
    md.setDay(17)
    md.setMonth(6)
    md.setYear(2019)
```

Ok, then the `MDYYYY()` method is defined in strange way. It's a method of a class `myDate`, but for some reason you're referring to the class, instead of simply using `self`:

```
def MDYYYY(self):
    print("%i/%i/%i" %(myDate.month, myDate.day, myDate.year))

#Should probably be defined instead like
def MDYYYY(self):
    print(f'{self.month}/{self.day}/{self.year}')
```

Also, you have issues with indentation and your class/method names are not Pythonic (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Answer (score 0):

So if someone else runs into a problem with this, here is the final code i used to solve the problem thanks for the people who commented and helped me out. Also i do not know why it inst showing the import and class in the code but all functions are tabed.

`import sys

class myDate:

```
#Constructer
def __init__(self, month, day, year):
    self.day = day
    self.month = month
    self.year = year   


#format for MDYYYY
def MDYYYY():
    print(f'{myDate.month}/{myDate.day}/{myDate.year}')
    
#format for MDYY
def MDYY():
    print(f'{myDate.month}/{myDate.day}/{myDate.year}')

#format for YYYYMD
def YYYYMD():
    print(f'{myDate.year}/{myDate.month}/{myDate.day}')

#mutator  to set Day of the month
def setDay(self, a):
    try:
        day = int(a)
        if day < 1 or day > 31:
            raise Exception("invalid day")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Invalid day")
        sys.exit( err )
    else:
        self.__day = day
    
#Mutator to set Month of the year
def setMonth(self, a):
    try:
        month = int(a)
        if month < 1 or month > 12:
            raise Exception("invalid month")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Invalid month")
        sys.exit( err )
    else:
        self.__month = month
        
#Mutator to set the year of the date
def setYear(self, a):
    try:
        day = int(a)
        if day < 1700:
            raise Exception("invalid year")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Invalid year")
        sys.exit( err )
    else:
        self.__year = year

# accessor to get day
def getDay(self):
    return self.__day

# accessor to get the month
def getMonth(self):
    return self.__month

# accessor to get the year
def getYear(self):
    return self.__year
```

if **name**=="**main**":
print()
print( "Instantiating object today and sorting value using .setMonth(6) .setDay(17) .setYear(2019)" )
myDate.day = 17
myDate.month= 6
myDate.year = 2019

```
# Print the date format for MM/DD/YYYY (01/01/2001)
print('Showing date in format- MM/DD/YYYY: ', end = '')
print(myDate.MDYYYY())
    
print("Instantiating object today and sorting value using .setMonth(7) .setDay(18) .setYear(2021)")
myDate.day = 18
myDate.month= 7
myDate.year = 2021

if myDate.year > 1699 and myDate.year < 1800:
    myDate.year = myDate.year - 1700
    
elif myDate.year > 1799 and myDate.year < 1900:
    myDate.year = myDate.year - 1800
    
elif myDate.year > 1899 and myDate.year < 2000:
    myDate.year = myDate.year - 1900

elif myDate.year > 1999 and myDate.year < 2100:
    myDate.year = myDate.year - 2000

# Print the date fomat for MM/DD/YY (01/01/01)
print('Showing date format - MM/DD/YY: ', end = '')
print(myDate.MDYY())

myDate.year = 2021
# Prints the date format for YYYY/MM/DD (2001/01/01)
print('Showing date format - YYYY/MM/DD: ', end ='')
print(myDate.YYYYMD())
print()`
```